# Id of an created element can't be used

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is:

I created an element:

```
var crt = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var lst = document.createTextNode("\u2103");
crt.appendChild(lst);
crt.id = "change";
$(".information").append(crt); // information is a div
```

When it is clicked, temperature is changing from Celsius to Fahrenheit and back:

```
var find = true;
var c;
var d = document.getElementById("change");
$( "#change" ).click(function() {
  if(find === true) {
    c = Math.trunc(s * 1.8 + 32); // s is the temperature in celsius from start
    t.innerHTML = "<br>Temperature: " + c;
    d.innerHTML = '&#8457;'

    find = false;
  } else {
    c = Math.trunc((c - 32) / 1.8);
    t.innerHTML = "<br>Temperature: " + c;
    d.innerHTML = "&#8451;";

    find = true;
  }
});
```

If i try to change something to id "change" on CSS, everything works fine.. But when i use it in script doesn't work.. But if the element with id "change" is created manually from the start on document, the code works.. Can you guys tell me what is the problem ? Why using it like this doesn't work ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either place your script tags just before the closing body tags, use `async` or `defer` on your script tags, or place you script on a ready handler.

Comment: It is executed after the body is loaded `body onload="function()"` and also the script is at the end of the body.

Comment: What, exactly _It is executed after the body is loaded_? Show the HTML and your `body.onload` handler please.

Comment: Full code: https://codepen.io/L1nkMzQ/pen/YLyvaY .

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The code on lines 49-67 in the supplied codepen execute and attempt to set a `click` handler on the element with the `id` of `change`. The element is not yet in the document when the code runs.

You will need to call that code after you dynamically create the element with the `id` of `change`.

Comment: Since the sample code seems to be using jQuery, one way to handle binding to the `click` event of this dynamically-added button is to use the `.on()` method.  You can bind to an element that is a parent of the button and that exists in the DOM when the page is loaded.  Something along the lines of `$("body").on("click", "#change", function() { /* your logic here... */ });`

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the problem.

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad to help. Please accept my answer if you feel it is appropriate.